# SQL Server 2008 express R2 logon problem after switch from workgroup to domain

Tags: dns, sql-server-express, workgroup

My network just passed to domain from workgroup and my SQL Express 2008 R2 refuses to start saying that the logon is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that the account you were using to start SQL Express is no longer valid.  Try going into Services and change the logon that the MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS service uses.

- Right-click on My Computer and choose Manage (using elevated privliges)
- Expand Services and Applications and click on Services
- Find SQL Server (MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS) in the list and double-click on it
- Click the Log On tab, give it the username and password you want to run SQL Server under.

You have to be local admin on your machine to make this change.

Comment: Excuse my inexperience, but how can I do that?

Comment: @Olivier Sorry, you probably saw my answer before I had the steps added.  Have a look at it now.

Comment: @Olivier Is there an error message that comes with that (instead of just the code)?

Comment: The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log... and in the event log: The SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service terminated with service-specific error 1814 (0x716).

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: I finally uninstalled everything and reinstalled and this corrected the problem.